# how to add x number of hours to datetime.datetime() in python

Tags: python, datetime

I have a datetime object, how to I add say 8 hour to this object?

```
example :
datetime.datetime(2021, 11, 19, 17, 6, 45)

to become --->
datetime.datetime(2021, 11, 20, 1, 6, 45)
```

Comment: One way of doing it is `datetime.datetime(2021, 11, 19, 17, 6, 45) + datetime.timedelta(hours=9)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `datetime.timedelta`:

```
import datetime

d = datetime.datetime(2021, 11, 19, 17, 6, 45)
t = datetime.timedelta(hours=8)

d+t
```

output: `datetime.datetime(2021, 11, 20, 1, 6, 45)`